# How to fix @date-io/moment with @material-ui/pickers? TypeError: utils.getDayText is not a function

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I've seen a lot of posts about this. I've tried downgrading versions of "moment" and "date-io/moment", but nothing works. I still see `TypeError: utils.getDayText is not a function` when clicking on the DatePicker component. Does anyone have any other suggestions?

```
"dependencies": {
"moment": "^2.24.0",
"@date-io/core": "^1.3.6",
"@date-io/moment": "^1.3.6",
"@material-ui/core": "^4.11.0",
"@material-ui/icons": "^4.9.1",
"@material-ui/pickers": "^3.2.10",
...

import moment from 'moment';
import MomentUtils from "@date-io/moment";
import {DatePicker, MuiPickersUtilsProvider} from '@material-ui/pickers';

const [displayDate, setDisplayDate] = useState(new Date());

const handleStartDateChange = async nextStartDate => {
    nextStartDate = moment.utc(nextStartDate).startOf('day');
    ...
    setDisplayDate(nextStartDate);
};

<MuiPickersUtilsProvider libInstance={moment} utils={MomentUtils}>
    <DatePicker
        value={displayDate}
        onChange={newDate => handleStartDateChange(newDate)}
        disableFuture={true}
        autoOk={true}
        fullWidth
      />
</MuiPickersUtilsProvider>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a new react app to just test the date picker. It worked. Turns out the issue was the `onChange()` function. First, I used `"@date-io/moment": "^1.3.13"`. But also the component should have directly used the state's `setDisplayDate()` instead of the custom function `handleStartDateChange()`.